# Write and look for directory in project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, filepath, relative-path, directory-structure

I am new on using paths and directories for web applications. I am making a project in Visual Studio working withg ASP and VB. Currently I want to get a list of some files in a specific directory of my project and then downloading a file in the same location. I am trying the following

```
For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
    Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath, "_Images/_MyImages"),
    FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.png")
    list.Add(foundFile)
Next
```

Unfortunately this gives me an error saying the directory does not exist, but it is pointing to a path directly in C:\ when the project is not located there. I have tried using paths like the following

```
"../_Images/_MyImages"
"~/_Images/_MyImages"
```

or even I have tried to use

```
ResolveUrl("~/_Images/_MyImages")
```

But I get pointed to a path in Program Files in which the exe file for the server is located. I know there's a difference on paths regarding the location in which it is located as project and when it is executed but I am not clear about how to use paths.

Comment: Have you tried `Server.MapPath("~/_Images/_MyImages")`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem completely.